# Multiply inverse of matricies

Tags: matrices

Let ${A}$ be a $2 \times 2$ 
matrix such that ${A}$ * $\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ -8 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad {A} * \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 7 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}.$
Find
${A}^{-1} *\begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}.$

What is the easiest way to start this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Start by multiplying your first two identities by $A^{-1}$ on the left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given

> $$
> \mathbf{A} \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ -8 \end{pmatrix}
> = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \quad \textrm{and} \quad
> \mathbf{A} \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 7 \end{pmatrix}
> = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
> $$

IF $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$ exists, we can write

> $$
> \mathbf{A}^{-1} \mathbf{A} \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ -8 \end{pmatrix}
> = \mathbf{A}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \quad \textrm{and} \quad
> \mathbf{A}^{-1} \mathbf{A} \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 7 \end{pmatrix}
> = \mathbf{A}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
> $$

Note that

> $$
> \mathbf{A}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}
> = -2 \mathbf{A}^{-1} \mathbf{A} \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ -8 \end{pmatrix}
> - \mathbf{A}^{-1} \mathbf{A} \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 7 \end{pmatrix}
> $$

So

> $$
> \mathbf{A}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}
> = -2 \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ -8 \end{pmatrix}
> - \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 7 \end{pmatrix}
> = \begin{pmatrix} -11 \\ 9 \end{pmatrix}
> $$

Thus

> $$
> \bbox[16px,border:2px solid #800000] { \mathbf{A}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}
> = \begin{pmatrix} -11 \\ 9 \end{pmatrix} }
> $$

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that $A$ is invertible since it transforms a basis of $\Bbb R^2$ to a basis of $\Bbb R^2$. Now write

$$A^{-1 }\cdot(-2,-1)^T=-2A^{-1}\cdot(1,0)^T-A^{-1}\cdot(0,1)^T$$
and the result follows.